# Error When Calling Procedure In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create a procedure in SQL Server. Here's my attempt so far:

```
create proc sp_cr_tbl(@table_name text)
--returns integer
as
begin
declare @sql nvarchar(4000)     
set @sql = 'create table @table_name(id integer)'
exec sp_executesql @sql
end
```

it created successfully but when I call

```
EXEC sp_cr_tbl 'tbl_9'
```

I am getting following error:

> ErrorMessage: Incorrect syntax near '@table_name'.

I am new to SQL Server, I was developing the same thing in PostgreSQL

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the info. I just started to work in MSSQL, I will correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code of your procedure to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cr_tbl (@table_name NVARCHAR(30))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @sql = 'create table ' + @table_name + ' (id integer)'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```

This is dynamic SQL and you need to append the name of the table you want to create to the command query (@sql) and then execute this.

You can add a `PRINT @sql` statement before `EXEC` to see exactly how the query will look like before it executes.

Also, I recommend that you do not use `TEXT` or `NTEXT` datatypes and pass the variable as `NVARCHAR`, because you've also set the datatype for @sql variable as `NVARCHAR`, and also give the parameter a size in the declaration of the procedure.

Also, take note of what @marc_s said, do not use `sp` as a prefix for your stored procedures as it has been reserverd by Microsoft.

Thus, in order to call the above stored procedure I recommend you use:

`EXEC cr_tbl @table_name='tbl_9'`

***Advice:***

It's not mandatory to specify the name of the parameter to which you are passing the variable, but I think it would come in handy in the future if you create stored procedures with multiple parameters and you want to pass multiple variables.

It will help to avoid errors if you explicitly specify what variables you pass to what parameters (*otherwise, if you don't then the order of the parameters you pass will matter!*).

Comment: `ErrorMessage: The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the add operator.` I've already tried this

Comment: @tamirda I was just getting to that. Try my modified answer.

Comment: @tamirda: get rid of that `text` datatype for your **parameter**!

Answer (score 0):

Below Query will help you

```
create proc sp_cr_tbl(@table_name text)
 --returns integer
as
begin
 declare @sql nvarchar(4000)     
  set @sql = 'create table ' + convert(nvarchar(4000), @table_name) + ' (id integer)'
  exec sp_executesql @sql
end
```

Comment: can you give a description :  why `convert(nvarchar(4000), @table_name)` ??

Comment: because you set the dynemic sql to @sql which is nvarchar(4000) so.

Comment: so you need to change procedure parameter or @sql datatype.